# I need to write a regex in Ruby that returns true / false

Tags: ruby, regex, startswith

I am trying to write a regex that takes a word and returns true for words starting with a vowel and returns false for words starting with a consonant. I have never written regex before, and I'm a little confused on how to write the expression. This is what I have so far:

```
def starts_with_a_vowel?(word)
  if word.match(/\A+[aeiou]/) == true
    return true
  else
    return false  
  end
end
```

Edit: So if word = "boat" , expression should return false. If word = "apple", expression should return true.

Comment: Should the last word of your first sentence be "consonant"? It would help if you would provide an example string and show what you want the result to be for that string (e.g., a string, an array, other?). When you give examples it's helpful if you assign a variable to each input (e.g., `str = "How now, brown cow?"`). That way readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define them.

Comment: Not regex but still... `str.capitalize.start_with?('A','E','I','O','U')`

Comment: You may have a reason for wanting to return `true` or `false`, but when a logical value is needed it is more common to return a "truthy" value (anything other than `nil` or `false`) or a "falsy" value (`nil` or `false`). For example: `'cat' =~ /a/ ? "meow" : "woof"` gives the same result as `!!('cat' =~ /a/) ? "meow" : "woof"` and is simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

OK.. So.. I never tested the code I formerly wrote.. it was meant only as some suggestion how to use the `match` with regex, but it not worked at all.. (that code snippet is now attached to the end of my answer fyi)

this here should be the working one:

```
def starts_with_a_vowel?(word)
  !!word.capitalize.match(/\A+[AEIOU]/)
end
```

..but how it was mentioned by Eric Duminil here below in comments, the method/function is
 not needed

`!!word.capitalize.match(/\A+[AEIOU]/)` can be used directly..
it returns `true` or `false`

but there are surely other (maybe better) solutions too..

..and here is the NOT working  code, which I formerly wrote:

```
def starts_with_a_vowel?(word)
  return word.match(/\A+[aeiou]/).length > 0
end
```

..the `match` method returns `nil` when not match and because `nil` has no `length` method defined, it raises `NoMethodError`

Comment: Much better, I'll revert my downvote. You don't need `return` by the way, and `/\A/` doesn't need a `+`

Comment: To make it clearer, you could put your first code at the end of your answer, explaining why it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

`word.match? /\A[aeiou]/i` is literally all you need. (ruby >= 2.4)

It matches the beginning of the string `\A` followed by a vowel `[aeiou]` in a case-insensitive manner `i` returning a bool `word.match?`

Before ruby 2.4 you have to use `word.match` and convert it to a bool, which is easiest done by logically negating it twice with `!!`

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of ways to do this.

**#1**

```
word = 'Ahoy'
!!(word[0] =~ /[aeiou]/i)
  #=> true
word = 'hiya'
!!(word[0] =~ /[aeiou]/i)
  #=> false
```

The regex reads, "match a vowel, case indifferently (`/i`)". `!!` converts a thruthy value to `true` and a falsy value (`nil` or `false`) to `false`:

```
!!0 = !(!0) = !(false) = true
!!nil = !(!nil) = !(true) = false
```

**#2**

```
word = 'Ahoy'
(word[0] =~ /[aeiou]/i) ? true : false
  #=> true
word = 'hiya'
(word[0] =~ /[aeiou]/i) ? true : false
  #=> false
```

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, so what I meant was it takes a word. Just a single word, not like a sentence. So the result should be boolean. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a lot of extra work for no reason. First, you don't need to check for equality with `true`; just `if *expression*` does the trick.

But in this case you don't need `if` at all. A regex match already returns a value that can be interpreted as a Boolean. `=~` returns the index of the match as an integer (which is "truthy"); `String#match` returns a `MatchData` object (which is also truthy). *Everything* in Ruby is truthy except `false` and `nil`, and `nil` is what both `=~` and `String#match` return if there's no match. So all you have to do is turn the result of one of those into the corresponding Boolean value, which you can do with `!!`. For example:

```
def starts_with_a_vowel? word
  !!(word =~ /^[aeiou]/)
end
```

That `!!` is read "not not", by the way. The `!` operator by itself treats its argument as Boolean and returns its opposite as an *actual* Boolean; that is `!(`*some truthy value*`)` returns `false` (not `nil`), and `!(`*some falsey value*`)` returns `true` (not just some truthy value). So applying `!` twice turns any truthy value into `true` and any falsey value (`false` or `nil`) into `false`.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you almost never need anything to return true or false. For boolean logic and `if/case/unless` statements, `truthy/falsey` are good enough. Also, don't forget to use case-insensitive Regex (with `//i`). `A` is a vowel :

```
class String
  def starts_with_a_vowel?
    self =~ /\A[aeiou]/i
  end
end

if "Airplane".starts_with_a_vowel?
  puts "Indeed"
end
#=> "Indeed"
```

If for some reason you really need `true/false` :

```
class String
  def starts_with_a_vowel?
    !(self =~ /\A[aeiou]/i).nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you use `^` here? Since we're dealing with strings isn't `\A` is the way to go?

Comment: You're correct. `"Plane\nAirplane".starts_with_a_vowel? #=> 6`. Thanks

Comment: I thought they were equivalent when not using `//m` modifier. But multiline modifier only seems to affect `.`, not `^` or `$`

Answer (score 1):

Do you **have** to use a regular expression? Just asking cause Ruby already provides [String#start_with?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F)

```
vowels = %w(a e i o u)
"boat".start_with?(*vowels)
# => false
"apple".start_with?(*vowels)
#=> true
```

Comment: `"A"`is a vowel too.

Comment: Yes. Though if you look at the original post you'll notice that the regex only specified lowercase vowels. If OP needs to match both cases they can either add the uppercase vowels to the `vowels` array or `downcase` the string before calling `start_with?`.